# Jquery .click() not work on safari.. but work on other browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

This code can run on chrome and firefox. but just the safari cannot make it work... what's the problem now? jquery should be no problem to run at all browser..

the click function element is on the button tag.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#loading-icon').hide();

    $('.complete-order').click(function() {
        $('#loading-icon').show();

        $(function () {
            count = 0;
            wordsArray = [" Please wait... loading...", " Don't close your browser...", " We are setting up your website...", " Running the system..." , " Almost complete..."];
            setInterval(function () {
                count++;
                $("#loading-icon span").fadeOut(400, function () {
                    $(this).text(wordsArray[count % wordsArray.length]).fadeIn(400);
                });
            }, 2000);
        });

    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="text-center padding-loading">
  <div id="loading-icon">
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> 
    <span> Please Wait... Loading...</span>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <button type="submit" id="btnCompleteOrder" class="complete-order btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="this.value='{$LANG.pleasewait}'">
button<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: what's the additional function for? `$(function () {`. That's the same as your `$( document ).ready(function() {`.. Not sure that's the issue but not needed is it?

Comment: Get rid of inner `$(function () {`

Comment: I already edit my code snippet.. u guy can try to run it

Comment: @Rick is the animation of text change ... u can run the code now.. I already edit my code snippet

Comment: Works for me in Safari.

Comment: @Fayaz weird.. in this code snippet it is working,, but in my working file .. it cannot work on safari...

Comment: JavaScript error somewhere else in your CODE perhaps (for safari).

Comment: what is it that is not working for you?

Comment: @Rick the loading-icon is hide.. is work.. but when i click the button.. the text never show ...

Comment: If there's a problem it's not in the code provided.. I'd still remove the additional `$(function () {` though..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try below code.

```
$(document).on("click",'.complete-order',function(){
// You code
});
```